# Applying an SQL column membership test for a variable number of patterns?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, python-2.7

I have a text input field on a webform that will take either a single string, or a comma-separated list of strings, the query an SQLite database. I'll read in a a single Python string in either case, then place each into a list:

```
all_jobs = [job.strip() for job in job_title_input.split(',')]
```

There will likely be no more than 3 comma-separated values ever, and in the vast majority of cases there will only be 1.

Rather than hardcode something like:

```
if len(all_jobs) == 1:
   cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE title LIKE '%?%""", (all_jobs[0]))
elif len(all_jobs) == 2:
   cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE title LIKE '%?%' OR LIKE '%?%'""", (all_jobs[0], all_jobs[1]))
else:
    #etc
```

Does SQL/SQLite allow me to make this more efficient, perhaps with its own version of Python's `in` membership test? I am imagining a conditional expression or another list comprehension, but can't get to formulating it, as my SQL knowledge is minimal.

Comment: IN and LIKE are not the same thing. You can easily use WHERE foo in (1,2,3) but you seem to want to match using wildcards

Comment: If I make a tuple from `all_jobs` and then `cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE title IN ?""", all_jobs)`?

Comment: No I guess that won't work as it's expecting the number of `?` to be equal to the length of `all_jobs`.

Comment: You can easily create the correct amount of placeholders based on the length

Comment: Something like `"""SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE title IN  (%s)""" % (', '.join(['%s'] * len(all_jobs), all_jobs)`